# Urlconnection IOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

currently I'm trying to read a file in a local server through URLConnection and URlRequest. It seems to work as it should until the changes in the file don't have any effect when I do the request again. Here's the code of how I'm building the request:

```
-(void)openURLConnectionWithString:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSTimeInterval timeout= 120;
    self.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:timeout];
    self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(urlConnection){
        NSLog(@"Connecting...");
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
    }
}
```

And this is how I make use of the class that contains the function above:

```
AsyncScheduleParser *getSchedule = [[AsyncScheduleParser alloc] init];
getSchedule.delegate = self;
[getSchedule openURLConnectionWithString:@"http://localhost/scheduleC.txt"];
[getSchedule release];
```

Only if I change the name of the file the changes appear once I read it again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to clean up all relevant objects (such as `self.receivedData`) once the request is completed. The best solution would be to simply create a new object for each request you're executing, and releasing this object once you're done.

Comment: The weird thing is... even after I restart the Apache and start up the simulator again, nothing changes once I've made the request I mean if I restart the app everything should be clean am I right?... BTW I have another object that do another request implementing the GDataXML and it works smoothly... both requests are built in the same way.